# Signalr client doesnt get callbacks until second client connects

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

I am using

- autofac.signalr2 v4.0.0
- microsoft.aspnet.signalr 2.2.2
- .net framework 4.6.1

using the owinstartup to deliver an IObservable to my hub
all good (AFAICT)

However in my JavaScript and .NET client I see a issue where:

1. start 1st client - successful start(). get no messages (no successful call to my javascript callbacks)
2. start 2nd client - now the 1st client starts to work, 2nd client gets no messages
3. start 3rd client - now 1st, 2nd client work, 3rd gets no messages

Here's a message the 2nd client was sent (when it was not working)

```
Sending outgoing message. Connection id: 12e1a17f-5f48-4e66-aece-166957d645cf, transport: WebSocketTransport, 
message: {"C":"d-142AA7E2-B,0|J,0|K,2|E,B3","M":[]}
```

then after the 3rd client is connected
2nd client gets this (which does work):

```
Sending outgoing message. Connection id: 12e1a17f-5f48-4e66-aece-166957d645cf, transport: WebSocketTransport, 
message: {"C":"d-142AA7E2-B,0\|J,0\|K,2\|E,B4","M":[{"H":"StreamHub","M":"receiveCallCanceled","A":[{"BaseTime":717006987,"BedIndex":2,"CallIndex":4,"EscalationIndex":5,"CallPlacedUTCTime":"2017-09-20T04:52:12.9831051Z","ServerSentUTCTime":"2017-09-20T04:52:15.4492756Z","FacilityGuid":"11111111-1bad-f00d-1111-111111111111","DialString":"1*111"}]}]}
```

notice that the connectionid is the same
It appears that the "M":[] is the reason the client isn't receiving the callbacks. Whats causing this?

**StartupOwin.cs**

```
builder.Register(c =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return new PCConsoleStreamObservable(c.Resolve<IClientGrainFactory>(),
                        c.Resolve<IFacilityConfigurationClient>());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError($"{ex}");
                    throw;
                }
            })
            .As<IObservable<XXXClientBase>>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
            .AutoActivate();

builder.RegisterHubs(typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly);

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration()
        {
            //EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
            //EnableJSONP = false,
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            Resolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container)
        };

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

        app.UseAutofacWebApi(httpConfig);
        app.UseAutofacMvc();
        app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);

        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
```

**StreamHub.cs**

```
public class StreamHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IObservable<XXXClientBase> _observer;

    public StreamHub(IObservable<XXXClientBase> observer) : base()
    {
        this._observer = observer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Groups appear to be the problem

```
        Clients
            .OthersInGroup(SignalRNameHelpers.GenerateStreamHubName(subscription))
            .receiveCallPlaced(outbound);
```

removing the group and sending to `All` fixed this issue

```
        Clients
            .All 
            .receiveCallPlaced(outbound);
```